# Object not found within array even though it is

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 object arrays (`allUsers` and `friendsOnTrip`). Both these arrays are of the same format. Each object within them contains details of a user (i.e. `firstName` and `lastName`). I am trying to make it that if an object in one array is not in the other one, then push that object to a new array, otherwise don't.

```
allUsers.forEach((user) => {
    if (friendsOnTrip.indexOf(user) <= -1) {
        this._friendsNotOnTrip.push(user);
    }
});
```

The problem is that even if the object `user` **seems** like it is in `friendsOnTrip`, then the expression of:

```
if (friendsOnTrip.indexOf(user) <= -1)
```

...will still evaluate to `true` *(which is wrong)* so I end up with objects within `this._friendsNotOnTrip` that shouldn't be there.

An example of one of the objects:

```
{
    email: "foo@bar.com",
    firstName: "foo",
    lastName: "bar",
    key: "123456789",
    friends: [
        "987654321",
        "246808642"
    ],
    location: {
        lng: -1.24567,
        lat: 50.9865
    },
    usersToSeeLocation: [
        "987654321"
    ]
}
```

The object at position 0 in `allUsers` and the object at position 0 in `friendsOnTrip` are the *same* object. I tested the individual attributes and got the following results:

```
console.log(allUsers[0].firstName === friendsOnTrip[0].firstName);                   //true
console.log(allUsers[0].lastName === friendsOnTrip[0].lastName);                     //true
console.log(allUsers[0].email === friendsOnTrip[0].email);                           //true
console.log(allUsers[0].friends === friendsOnTrip[0].friends);                       //false
console.log(allUsers[0].key === friendsOnTrip[0].key);                               //true
console.log(allUsers[0].location === friendsOnTrip[0].location);                     //false
console.log(allUsers[0].usersToSeeLocation === friendsOnTrip[0].usersToSeeLocation); //false

console.log(allUsers[0] === friendsOnTrip[0]);                                       //false
```

Looking inside `friends`, `usersToSeeLocation`, and `location` in both `allUsers[0]` and `friendsOnTrip[0]`, the contents are the exact same so I am unsure as to why those expressions are evaluating to `false`.

Comment: They're not the same object. They hold the same information but they're still deferent object with different space in memory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object comparison in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript)

Comment: Do both the `Objects` have same keys as well as values?? If so then you can try with **JSON.stringify** both the Objects and then compare. If both the `Objects` have same key but having different values then It must be `return` false.

Comment: How to tell if two objects are different? What are the keys that only identify one object from the other?

Comment: @Ashish there is no guarantee the keys have the same order, so JSON.stringify comparisons are unstable

Comment: @fafl : Yes It will work only if both the objects have same key value pair.

Comment: @Ashish {a:1, b:2} might become "{b:2, a:1}" after stringify

Comment: @fafl : I don't think so that would be the case you can try. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't compare objects like this. For example

```
[{a: 1, b:2}].indexOf({a: 1, b:2})
```

returns -1. Instead you should search for a specific property, something like

```
allUsers.forEach((user) => {
    if (friendsOnTrip.map(u => u.key).indexOf(user.key) <= -1) {
        this._friendsNotOnTrip.push(user);
    }
});
```

Comment: possibly, the email.

Comment: you could also create a string of multiple properties by concatenating them

Comment: This has worked, thank you! I had completely forgotten about using `.map()`

Answer (score 0):

*"Looking inside friends, usersToSeeLocation, and location in both allUsers[0] and friendsOnTrip[0], the contents are the exact same so I am unsure as to why those expressions are evaluating to false."*

that's because they are not the same. The have the same value BUT they are not the same object! that's why your "===" returns false
You have to compare all indexes one by one

you can do array1.join() === array2.join() to do your comparition faster